# How to know if the device is MC9090G with RFID or not in C#

Tags: c#, compact-framework, device

I'm developing in C# for devices MC9090G and I'm trying to know in my code if the device has or not RFID to load determined drivers; I've used SPI_GETOEMINFO from the coredll.lib library but this returns the same model: "MC9090G" for both devices, how can I know which one has RFID?

Comment: Our devices (Datalogic Falcons) have a field that can be populated in the About box of the Device Settings. I have to manually go in and set the Serial Numbers for each device when I set them up, otherwise I don't know how to tell one device from the other.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but how could I distinguish them in C#, how could I retrieve that serial number? I have many devices MC9090G so I can't code by serial number, it has to be generic. I couldn't find a way to difference them in the code.

Comment: If the RFID-capable device has a specific RFID dll or driver, you could look for that to distinguish capabilities.

Comment: Yes I agree, but how could I retrieve that value in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking for solutions to distinguish between devices with RFID or not, I used the Symbol.RFID.dll assembly to create an RFID.Reader instance:

```
Symbol.RFID.Reader info = new Symbol.RFID.Reader();
```

So, when the device doesn't have RFID this line throws a System.Exception 'exception'; so I'm handling this exception to do what I want with devices without RFID.

I know this try catch is not the best solution, but it worked for me.

Thanks everybody for having answered.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read what the manufacturer hard coded into your device, you should get [Motorola's Developer Tool](http://support.symbol.com/support/browse.do?WidgetName=BROWSE_PRODUCT&TaxoName=SG_SupportGoals&BROWSE_PRODUCT.isProductTaxonomy=true&BROWSE_PRODUCT.NodeId=SG_MC9090CE_1_2&BROWSE_PRODUCT.thisPageUrl=/product/products.do&id=m4&BROWSE_PRODUCT.TaxoName=SG_SupportGoals&NodeType=leaf&NodeName=MC9090%20CE&BROWSE_PRODUCT.NodeType=leaf&NodeId=SG_MC9090CE_1_2&AppContext=AC_ProductPage&param_document=sp).

If you would rather set the device's Serial Number on your own, you can use the **Device name** field from the **About** box: Go into **Settings** (Start > Settings), launch the **About** applet, then tab over to the **Device ID** screen.

[image: screenshot]

From here, you can replace the default value (`Pocket_PC` in the pic above) with the Serial Number of your device ...or whatever you'd care to write in there.

This field can be read from the registry as follows:

```
using Microsoft.Win32.Registry;

private static string _deviceId = null;

public static string DeviceName {
  get {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_deviceId)) {
      using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Ident", true)) {
        try {
          _deviceId = (string)key.GetValue("Name", "[Unnamed]");
        } catch (Exception e) {
          ErrorWrapper("GetDeviceName", e);
          _deviceId = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
        } finally {
          key.Flush();
          key.Close();
        }
      }
    }
    return _deviceId;
  }
}
```

Notice this particular **getter** will only read from the Registry once, then store the value for any further use. Probably not necessary, though, since Registry reads are designed to be fast.

Of course, if your employees forget to put the mobile device on the charger and it goes dead, you'll have to enter it again.

Comment: Ok, really thanks for answering, this solution works, yes, but for me the problem is that I can't set serial number or something to the devices, I don't have access to them, so I have to distinguish those devices from something more than their model (I've tried retrieving their model but it doesn't give me enough information).

Comment: Did you download the [Motorola Symbol Developer Tools](http://support.symbol.com/support/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=13843&sliceId=&dialogID=471106113&stateId=1%200%20471090988) for your device, install that, and use it in Visual Studio? That should allow you to read everything specific to MC9090 devices.

Comment: Yes, I did it but I couldn't find what I'm looking for, I'm still searching how to distinguish those devices with EMDK.

Answer (score 1):

If you download the [Motorola EMDK](http://www.motorola.com/Business/US-EN/Business+Product+and+Services/Software+and+Applications/Mobility+Software/Mobile+Application+Utilities/EMDT-EMCT_US-EN), there is a class called TerminalInfo in the  Symbol.ResourceCoordination namespace of the Symbol.ResourceCoordination.dll assembly. Create an instance of this class and then read the ESN property to get the actual hardware serial number of the device.

The same class also contains properties that can be used to determine the installed hardware though I have not used these myself and cannot tell you off the top of my head how they should be interrogated.

Comment: Thanks for answering Martin, I'm gonna try this ESN property and notify you how it was.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution, I've tried the TerminalInfo property in the Symbol.ResourceCoordination.dll assembly, it returns the installed hardware configuration, but I couldn't find the RFID configuration, but it has a the configuration for TouchPad, Camera, Audio, Bluetooth. So, I'm gonna post my solution with Symbol.RFID.dll assembly